# How to fixed error "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing."

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am doing a command that apply roles to the member when they enter `?getroles` to the bot in discord. 
It said the required argument, `member` is missing but I had put it inside my code.

```
@client.command()
async def getoroles(ctx,member):
    grabtherole = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="test")
    await client.add_roles(member,grabtherole)
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.display_name} get {grabtherole}')
```

but it shows error when I run this command (send `?getroles` in discord)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

May I know how to fix it? 
I'm a beginner of doing discordpy and I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument` means you havent provided the parameter `member`. You should run `?getrole <mention>` not just `?getrole`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'server' ` this is the error code after i run the command together with the mention. Sorry for disturbing and can u teach me the way to fix it?

Comment: so u should make yout def statement like this ```async def getoroles(ctx,member:discord.Member):```

Comment: So u can mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can get role like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def getrole(ctx)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.role, name="your_role_name")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{role} was added to {ctx.author.display_name}!!")
```

And If you want to add a optional argument in the command. You do like this.

```py
async def getrole(ctx, arg=None)
```

Add None as a default value to it.

Comment: It's work perfectly, thanks. I search a lots of tutorial and they only teach how to add roles to the new members. This is a good way to add role by using command

Comment: Glad I could help.